# Change Settings based on IOS version

Tags: iphone, settings

I have a settings screen that contains my own custom font menu. Some of these fonts in this list only exist in iOS 4.X and cause problems if selected in iOS 3. How can I use different plists based on which version of iOS is installed?

Thanks for your help.

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class to get the model name , version number of your device.

```
NSString* deviceName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
NSString* deviceVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
```

Based on the value of above variable , you could use the different set of plist.

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. My question was how to set the plist that will be used on the settings screen based on the iOS version. Your code is going to help determine the iOS version but how do you change the plist? Thanks

Comment: @iphaaw: you could either have separate plist for the different iOS version in you application or have everyting in single plist file with different key, like FONT_TITLE_LABEL_KEY1 XYZ , FONT_TITLE_LABEL_KEY2 ABC ,

Comment: Jhaliya, I realise that I can use UIDevice and that I can have multiple plists but how do you cause the right plist to be used in the settings screen? Thanks. Iphaaw

Comment: @iphaaw: you could have different name for plist, for example deviceOne.plist & devicetwo.plist .

Comment: Yes I realise this. My question is how do you invoke these two different plists. Just by magically renaming them won't do this I'm sure. A small code sample would be much appreciated. Thanks for your help.